# How to add Each Contact Membership fee using webform civicrm in drupal7

Tags: civicontribute, civimember, webform-civicrm

I have 2 contacts(Contact1 & contact2) in webform, I Want each contact get membership fee.(like In civicrm while creating new membership with Record payment Registration, it will create membership fee.)
Trail: for this problem i created contribution page of financial type is "membership fee" in civicrm. this page is selcted in webform contribution tab, after submitting form it showing membership fee added only in contact1 not added in contact2,3,4.., so i want to add membership fee in each contact.
[image: In this image tell that contribution amount will add to contact1 not contact2,3,4...]

Answer (score 1):

The first problem I see in your screenshot is that you've set up Contact 1 as an organization. Really, contact 1 needs to represent the person who is filling out the webform and paying for the membership. An organization, generally, cannot operate a keyboard & mouse. Fix that and the rest ought to make more sense.